# [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named serial_node.py below /opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosserial_python

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I tried to execute this, I got following error:

```
glv@VaraPrasad:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun rosserial_
rosserial_arduino  rosserial_client   rosserial_msgs     rosserial_python
glv@VaraPrasad:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun rosserial_python 
message_info_service.py  serial_node.py           
glv@VaraPrasad:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM1
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named serial_node.py below /opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosserial_python
```

In this [Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World) I encountered this rosrun statement, why we need to run this     `glv@VaraPrasad:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM1`
what is the use of it. And how to overcome this error??

Thanks In Advance

`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309071/%5Brosrun%5D-couldn%27t-find-executable-named-serial_node.py-below-/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosserial_python/) by [GLV](https://answers.ros.org/users/37187/glv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-11-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have a lokal copy of rosserial in you workspace  , you may try also  this

```
sudo pip install pyserial
```

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-09-14**:
Thi Solution  helped here https://m.blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=chandong83&logNo=220851255045&categoryNo=61&proxyReferer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de%2F

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-14**:
Please don't post link-only answers/comments to sites outside of `ros.org`.

Include the main parts of the answer/solution in your answer/comment itself.

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-09-14**:
I think it is also not right to take the solution from others an do not honor them.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-14**:
It goes without saying that if/when you create an answer based on an external site, or quote large parts of it, you always include a link to the source.

Including a link `!=` posting only a link.

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-09-14**:
I try to diliver better answers

**Comment by [GLV](https://answers.ros.org/users/37187/glv/) on 2019-09-16**:
Thanks Mr. #duck-development.